# SEMP API equivalent for url "/SEMP/v2/config/msgVpns/default"

Tags: solace

URL `.../SEMP/v2/config/msgVpns/default` returns data

```
{
    "data":{
        "authenticationBasicEnabled":true,
        "authenticationBasicProfileName":"default",
        "authenticationBasicRadiusDomain":"",
        "authenticationBasicType":"radius",
        "authenticationClientCertAllowApiProvidedUsernameEnabled":false,
....
```

What is the Java API to return this data? Apparently there is no `getMsgVpnsDefault(...)` method

Generally speaking what is the translation of URL's into API calls?  This doesn't seem to be addressed in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the Java API to return this data? Apparently there is no getMsgVpnsDefault(...) method

There's no API provided by Solace.
SEMP(v2 in your case) is a series of REST commands to be executed over the management port to manage the configuration of the Solace routers.

This is not to be mistaken for the Java API that's provided for messaging over the messaging port/interface.

> Generally speaking what is the translation of URL's into API calls?

The complete list of URL's is documented here:
https://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/swagger-ui/index.html#/

Comment: If Solace can call it an "API", then I can call it an "API": "Solace Element Management Protocol version 2 (SEMP v2) is a RESTful API that you can use to configure Solace message routers."  http://dev.solace.com/tech/semp/

Answer (score 0):

In the Solace Samples repository on GitHub there's a gradle file which uses Swagger CodeGen to generate a POJO wrapper around SEMP v2.

This then gives you a Java API to interact with Solace routers.

WRT your original question about getMsgVpnsDefault(...) I believe you'd use 

`MsgVpn defaultVPN = sempApiInstance.getMsgVpn("default", null);`

Or you could grab the list of all VPNs

`MsgVpnsResponse resp = sempApiInstance.getMsgVpns(1000, null, null, null);
List<MsgVpn> allVpsn = resp.getData();`

then iterate over the list checking until you find one whose name is "default"

https://github.com/SolaceSamples/solace-samples-semp/tree/master/java

Comment: There is a partial swagger spec for the Monitor side of the SEMP v2 API available on the latest VMRs (8.9.0.1008) at http://127.0.0.1:8080/SEMP/v2/monitor/spec I've forked the Solace samples repository and added an example of its usage here: https://github.com/MichaelHussey/solace-samples-semp